# Node-inspector not init breakpoints

Tags: node.js

I run node server in console  [image]

Then in browser :8080/debug?port=5858
i see 
[image]

My breakpoint doesnt work . 
Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run node-inspector after your app.

Also, in your case, it seems by the time you start inspector, the app will be past the section you want to debug. So try this:

```
# Console window 1
node --debug-brk run.js

# Console window 2
node-inspector
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858`

The execution should be stopped on the first line of code. Set up your breakpoints and resume.